# Get value of item from array class property dynamically in PHP

Tags: php

I have an object named Model like this:

```
class Model {
    public $menu;
}
```

In a function I instantiate a new Model like this:

```
public function Hello(){
    $model = new Model();
    $model->menu['home'] = 'Hi there';
}
```

---

In my plan I have a Model class that can contain several properties. These properties I want to be able to get them in my view (html file). There are `<!-- $model.{PropertyName} -->` elements that are replaced by the property value that is available in the Model class. In this specific scenario I have a property `$menu` that is an `array` like displayed above.

---

Now, I have some piece of code that extracts a string value where the result of this string is `menu['home']`. With this string I try to read the model it's property `menu`.

So:

```
private function Action($model){
    $foo = "menu['home']";

    //Get value of $foo
    $value = $model->$foo;

}
```

I expect to get 'Hi there' but instead I get an Notice :
`Notice: Undefined property: Model::$menu['home'] in ....script.php on line X`

When I directly access the property it works!

Any idea how I can get the array item it's value?

Comment: Why don't you do `$value = $model->menu['home'];` ?

Comment: because it's a variable value; I just put there for example ;-)

Comment: Can you please clarify?

Answer (score 1):

Your `$model` instance doesn't have a member with the name `menu['home']` so you can't really access it this way. You have several options here:

### option 1 - split the string and use two variables:

```
$foo = "menu";
$bar = "home";

//Get value of $foo[$bar]
$value = $model->{$foo}[$bar];
```

You can also split it using php code if you don't the values in two different variables.

### option 2 - use eval (which i really recommend against!)

```
$foo = "menu['home']";

//Get value of $foo

die('ARE YOU SURE YOU REALLY WANT THIS?!?!?!');

$value = eval('return $model->'.$foo.';');
var_dump($value);
```

> Note that using `eval` when not required is really **not a good practice!!!** and makes your code **vulnerable**.

Comment: I see... Thanks. Simple reasoning behind it is that `$menu` is an array, but apparently the `$foo` isn't evaluated all the way. Option 1 is not really an option and I don't like the `eval` either. I'll explain myself in my post.

Answer (score -1):

To solve this, you need a PHP-Mechanism which is called "variable variables" (see http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) for more Information.

In your case, you can access your variable by:
`$value = $model->${$foo};`